# R complains about missing .so file but its the package name

Tags: r, c

I am trying to write my first `R` package that relies on some `C` code to be called. As a first pass I am using Hadley's book https://r-pkgs.org/ to try and work out some examples but for some reason I keep getting an error that a .so cannot be found. The weird part is, is that the .so file is the package name which is why I understand it's missing, but can't figure out why `R` is looking for it. I'm guessing that I am probably doing something wrong with the `useDynLib()` function, but I can't figure out what it is. I'm pretty sure I followed Hadley's example in section 15.2.1 correctly (found here: https://r-pkgs.org/src.html#src-debugging) but am at a loss for what the issue is.

In order to try and make the problem reproducible, here are some screen shots and R code that I am using.

This is what my `R` package looks like:

[image]

and my NAMESPACE file looks like the following:

[image]

Inside of the src folder I have my add_.so file which was made from the following C code:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP add_(SEXP x_, SEXP y_) {
  double x = asReal(x_);
  double y = asReal(y_);
  
  double sum = x + y;
  
  return ScalarReal(sum);
}
```

and inside the R folder I have an R file called add.R which is the following:

```
#' @export
#' @useDynLib myfirstpackage add_
add <- function(x, y) .Call(add_, x, y)
```

When I try to build the package I get the following error:

```
==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source myfirstpackage

* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library’
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
* installing *source* package ‘myfirstpackage’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-myfirstpackage/00new/myfirstpackage/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
No man pages found in package  ‘myfirstpackage’ 
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘myfirstpackage’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘myfirstpackage.so’ not found
```

myfirstpackage is the name of the package, and so I am confused as to why it is looking for a .so file associated with it.

And for what it's worth, I have read through the `R` manual and tried looking at other packages on CRAN to see if they are doing something differently, but have yet to figure out where my error lies.

If anything else is needed for reproducibility purposes, just let me know and I will add it.

Comment: How do you create `add_.so`? The default for an r package would be `myfirstpackage.so`. And it seems missing this file is what R is complaining about.

Comment: @RalfStubner So I have a separate directory called myfirstpackageC where I have all my .c  files. From the terminal I go into that directory and run R CMD SHLIB add_.c From there I move the add_.so file into the src directory in myfirstpackage directory.

Comment: Is this approach blatantly wrong? I've just been moving the .so files into my package in the src directory.

Comment: That's indeed not how one does it. But all the `.c` files into the `src` folder of your main package. `R CMD INSTALL` will then automatically create the correct `.so` file for you.

Comment: @RalfStubner Thank you so much! Very silly question then, does the package have to contain the .c files? Or is there a way to just have the .so files  be included?

Comment: The above should have read "Put all the `.c` files into the `src` folder ...". So yes, they have to be part of the (source) package.

Comment: Thanks @RalfStubner That solved everything for me! If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: How about you write up your solution as answer?